# TreeView Control Modify parent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView control and I would like after the tree has been completely loaded in the form, to traverse it and update a number of parent nodes by painting on top of them using 2D Graphics. What is the event that is raised after the the tree has been completely loaded which can also pass parameters with Graphics so I can start painting the parent nodes?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you add a handler after whatever is creating the treeview? Then you do whatever you wantv from there...

Comment: You need to set the DrawMode of the TreeView to hook into the drawing routine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565072/treeview-with-custom-drawn-treenode